# Spacemacs, Lisp, Pasting and the missing Space

Tags: spacemacs, evil, whitespace, yank, paredit

When editing Lisp or Clojure in Spacemacs (Emacs with Evil) I find the pasting behavior anoying. Say I have yanked `bar` and want to paste it as a parameter to `(foo)` so I get `(foo bar)`. The problem is, I have to insert a space between `o` and `)` before pasting or afterwards.

Is there a way to tell Spacemacs to automatically insert the space in Lisp/Clojure mode (with paredit) when pasting?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a regular command for that (maybe there is one in the emacs-lisp state) but of course you could define your own custom function. e.g.

```
(defun custom-lisp-paste (&optional count)
  (interactive "*P")
  (forward-char)
  (insert " ")
  (evil-paste-after count))
```

And bind it to your prefered key. you could optionally add `evil-forward-word-end` before forward-char.
I am using `evil-paste-after` and `evil-forward-word-end` here, but I think generally it is preferable to use the underlying Emacs functions directly. It is described in the [Emacs lisp intro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Yanking.html#Yanking) by Chassell how to insert text from the kill ring...